# Agent unable to print all results received from Axion library request in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, axios, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to print all results received from the following request (this code not working):

```
function searchForProducts(agent) {
   // category_name = 'Cooking' for example
   const category_name = agent.parameters.category_name;  
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       axios.get(`https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/qvlk728a5p23g/search?Categories=*${category_name}*&Status=1`).then(function (res) {
           let Categories = res.data[0];

           if (Categories) {                
                for(var i=0;i<res.data.length;i++){
                    agent.add(`https://alaswadtrading.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=${Categories.ProductID}\n\n${Categories.Name}`);
                }
           } else {
                agent.add(`No items found in the selected category (${category_name})`);
           }

           resolve();
       });
   });      
}
```

The problem I'm facing is the agent can only print on result through the following code (this record working but return only one URL):

```
function searchForProducts(agent) {
   const category_name = agent.parameters.category_name;  
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       axios.get(`https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/qvlk728a5p23g/search?Categories=*${category_name}*&Status=1`).then(function (res) {
           let Categories = res.data[0];

           if (Categories) {
                agent.add(`https://alaswadtrading.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=${Categories.ProductID}\n\n${Categories.Name}`);
           } else {
                agent.add(`No items found in the selected category (${category_name})`);
           }

           resolve();
       });
   });  
    
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

============ After Applying Proposed Solution ================

**Hello, since yesterday I'm testing but with no luck to get the exact problem. Here what I did:**

1. I created new Intent which will trigger your code once "Test" received.
2. I have test the code using different ways, and here the result:

`Category_Name = “Cooking”`:

**- Dialogflow Agent Test:** Worked (https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Uis.jpg).

**- Web Agent Test:** Not Worked (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLWNU.jpg).

**- Dialogflow Web Messenger:** Worked (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmSRi.jpg).

**- Twilio:** Not Worked (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu4hG.jpg) and error message was (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rVaz.jpg).

But, when I changed the `Category_Name = “Small%20Appliances”`:

**- Dialogflow Agent Test:** Worked (https://imgur.com/undefined).

**- Web Agent Test:** Worked (https://imgur.com/undefined).

**- Dialogflow Web Messenger:** Worked (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1be6R.jpg).

**- Twilio:** Worked (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKpKF.jpg).

Here a link for web test (I will keep `Category_name=’Cooking’`) so you can see the result:

https://bot.dialogflow.com/004077c2-d426-472c-89f0-4997e2955d59

What do you think?

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine for me, but it seems that it only loops through `res.data[0]` 29 times. Is this expected? Also what error are you getting at your 1st code? Can you edit your question and include the error as well?

Comment: The output I got is `https://alaswadtrading.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=2 BEKO STANDARD COOKER HOOD 60CM - INOX` being shown 29 times.

Comment: Hi, there is no error but no result appear for me, can you show me how the result appearing for you with 29 products? When I put the code, the agent return nothing for me, can you guide me?

Comment: This is the result when I use the first code snippet, nothing. check out this snapshot (https://imgur.com/SgPQ4ud), but when I put below code snippet I got result, check out this snapshot (https://imgur.com/KFtgmvr). What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code above I was able to loop through `agent.add()` and got the results. I used `test` as user input that matches intent "test intent".

Here is a snippet of the 29 similar outputs of your code provided:

[image]

---

Here is the full code:

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const axios = require('axios'); 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });


  function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
   const category_name = 'Cooking';  
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       axios.get(`https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/qvlk728a5p23g/search?Categories=*${category_name}*&Status=1`).then(function (res) {
           console.log(res.data);
           let Categories = res.data[0];

           if (Categories) {                
                for(var i=0;i<res.data.length;i++){
                    agent.add(`https://alaswadtrading.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=${Categories.ProductID}\n\n${Categories.Name}`);
                }
           } else {
                agent.add(`No items found in the selected category (${category_name})`);
           }

           resolve();
       });
   }); 
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('test intent', yourFunctionHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0",
    "actions-on-google": "2.2.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.6.1",
    "axios": "0.21.1"
  }
}
```

---

Just a suggestion, since your objective is to show all products under a certain "category" you might want to loop through the whole `res.data`. In this example I just used `category_name = 'Cooking'` and printed all products that is under the specified category.

```
function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
   const category_name = 'Cooking';  
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       axios.get(`https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/qvlk728a5p23g/search?Categories=*${category_name}*&Status=1`).then(function (res) {
           let Categories = res.data;
           if (Categories) {                
                 for (const product of Categories ){
                    agent.add(`https://alaswadtrading.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=${product.ProductID}\n\n${product.Name}`);
                }
           } else {
                agent.add(`No items found in the selected category (${category_name})`);
           }

           resolve();
       });
   }); 
  }
```

This will result to:
[image]

Comment: Dear, I have edited the the question and reply you with the strange result I got, please take a look.

Comment: @alawibh you get errors for "Web Test Agent" because it does not support line breaks as per https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/web-demo#limits. For twilio I'm not sure since the [dialogflow response](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/blob/master/twilio/server.js#L53) is only being sent to the Twilio API. You can check [Twilio API docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml/message) for more details.

Comment: Hi again, I saw that web test agent does not support breaks, but it showed the result once you put Category_Name = “Small%20Appliances”, look on the attached snapshot, it ignore "\n\n" and respond (https://imgur.com/xiMXEFz)

Comment: I see, since your latest question is specific for dialogflow web test agent. I suggest to create a new question so the community can contribute! :)

Comment: Hi dear, yes, as you said, your solution worked for Dialogflow. I will see what to do for the rest.

Comment: Dear friend, could you please clearify for me what is the difference between using promise along with axios.get compared with using axios.get alone and how this can affect the results?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with axios, you can post a new question so community members that are knowledgeable in axios can help you out.